# How can I add static Extention method to a existing class in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods

for example, I can to use `Color` (the building class like that)

```
Color c = Color.GreenSmile();
```

this is my extension method, But I don't want to use an Instance. It is possible?

```
   public static Color GreenSmile(this Color color)
        {
           return Color.FromArgb(83, 255, 26);
        }
```

Comment: _"But I don't want to use an Instance"_ What you want instead? An extension method needs an object

Comment: I want a static method, to use the name of the class..

Comment: But I prefer to use the Color class...   If it is posible...

Comment: "Extension everything" is/was a proposed feature for C#8. Not landed yet.

Comment: An extension-method is nothing but a static method that **expects an instance of your class**. If you don´t have an instance, use a normal static method: `public static Color GreenSmile()`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  You mean that is impossible?

Comment: @TimSchmelter  It is impossible to Extension a class? I must use an object for that?

Comment: But I see now [hasn't made it into C# 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/12/building-c-8-0/) (search for `Extension Everything` in the comments)

Comment: @jon create a static class name it ColourExtensions and put that extension method there.

Comment: @LeszekRepie That won´t change anything, as an extension-method still expects an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't omit the `Color` instance because an extension method needs an instance of the type it extends as first argument and the `this` keyword.

> I want a static method, to use the name of the class.

You *could* create a new class `Color` in it's own namespace, although that could cause confusion.

```
namespace Drawing.Utilities
{
    internal class Color
    {
        public static System.Drawing.Color GreenSmile()
        {
            return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(83, 255, 26);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this method as it was a `System.Drawing.Color` method:

```
var greenSmile = Color.GreenSmile(); // add using Drawing.Utilities;
```

But as mentioned above this can cause confusion, espcially because the method returns a different `Color`-type than itself. So it 's certainly better to use a different name for this class(`ColorUtility`).

Answer (score 0):

An extension-method is nothing but a static method that **expects an instance of your class**. However in your case you don´t seem to use the provided instance at all, so you can simply omit it from the method-signature and turn it into a normal static method:

```
public static Color GreenSmile()
{
    return Color.FromArgb(83, 255, 26);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
Color c = MyClass.GreenSmile();
```

Comment: You mean to put all of that in the same class?
I want to create a DLL of that and use it on other project

Comment: The method isn´t know to `System.Drawing.Color`, so you have to use the name of the class where the method is defined, in my case `MyClass`.

Comment: @jon just a suggestion: make yourself a solution jon.utils and add a project jon.utils.extensions, then put all those kind of things into it. Even if you decide not to use the whole dll, you have a project with snippets for later use. I did that and it helped me alot, for autodidactic purpose too. If i am lazy, i just copy&paste one of that snippets into my current work SomeProject/Extensions/SomeExtensionSnippet.cs